# Bootstrap theme doesn't work in Angular cli project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried using a bootstrap theme in my project but it seems to behave different and I don't understand what's wrong. I wrote this in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/minty/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The result I get is the following:
[image]

But the theme on the original website looks like this:
https://bootswatch.com/minty/

Comment: Looks pretty similar to me except for some text centering.. Can you zero in on some specific problems?

Comment: Did you use Chrome to inspect the elements that are different? What is your html structure for the page?

Comment: @JCFord the alignment of the elements is what bothers me, I need it to be the same for my elements as on the website.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I took the html body from the original page, in order to check it. The elements appear to be the same as structure

Comment: Then, as Daniel suggested, inspect the elements in Chrome and see where the text centering is coming from. Most likely you have css entries or style tags of your own.

Comment: Thank you both, I will try to find the error with Chrome tools as I forgot about them before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using in the index.html, add the styling sheet to `.angular-cli.json`

Step 1: Download bootstrap and the theme minty bootstrap

Step 2: Add to angular cli under styles and scripts

```
"styles": [
        "../pathTo/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "myStyles.css"
 ],
"scripts": [
        "../pathTo/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```